# Pivot Tables in MS Excel (Office 365)

Tags: excel, excel-2010

I have conducted a Survey whose responses are tabulated in excel. Reponses on 7 different questions are measured. For each question, a response could be any of 5 values: *not at all*, *slightly*, *moderately*, *very*, *extremely*.

I am trying to create a table that will count number of values for each of the 5 types of responses across seven questions, but unable to achieve that using Pivot Table.

Input table:

[image: Data on which Pivot Table is built]

Desired output table:
[image]

The problem is that count values of Q1 get copied in columns for Q2, Q3, Q4, and so on. If I drag Q2, Q3, Q4 in rows of the pivot table field then it begins to separate the responses of each type, creating a big mess e.g. shown below:

[image]

Comment: What you are covering in red can be seen and is also shown below...

Comment: You should post a better data example, actual image does not help. Also, try it to be something easy to copy/paste. My first guess is that your actual design does not allow to pivot as you wish

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need to use a pivot table?  Can you not use the countif() function?  If you create the required result table and just use the countif() function on the data to get the required result.